# SPI (file based) from Rasp Pi to Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to use file-based SPI communication from my Raspberry Pi to an Arduino (328p based). The weird thing is that when I write it out one byte at a time and flush the buffer between each write it works, but I cannot just send it a large buffer all at once. What's really weird about it is that when I do, *some* of the data goes through until there is a 0 in the byte array being sent and then it just ignores everything after that. So I don't *think* it's a speed issue.  See python code below with both what works and what doesn't. Arduino side has SPI handling code that I know to work perfectly between it and another Arduino, so I'll exclude that for brevity.

```
dev = '/dev/spidev0.0'
spi = open(dev, "wb")

buffer = bytearray()

#fill the buffer here

#this works
for i in range(len(buffer)):
        spi.write(struct.pack("B", buffer[i]))
        spi.flush()

#this does NOT work
spi.write(buffer)
spi.flush()
```

Any thoughts as to why, when writing multiple bytes at once, it just gives up once it sees a 0?

Comment: Your description suggests that the variation of the spi.write() method is interpreting the 0 as a terminating null.  Either that, or there is an error in your arduino code exposed or concealed by certain timings between bytes.

Answer (score 1):

First I assume that You don't use spidev library because want to play with direct file access to learn.

Have you tried if a byte of 0xFF (all 1'ns) will break communication too?

Hoe is the mode of SPI on both ends, I am referring to CPOL and CPHA

I have not tried sending an ioctl command in python but it is possible se [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html)

You can maybe use this [example](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-spi/) in c, first to test your communication with different settings of mode, then as inspiration on how to set mode using ioctl in python.

Answer (score 0):

I assume; just using the open function creates a standard file object. In a standard file "0" is the "EOF" flag, so the write function closes the file. I was looking into writing directly to the SPI device file as well. It looks like the best solution would be to `import os` and use `os.open()`I haven't tried it yet, but in theory it should solve the issue; you had.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `io.write()` can handle zero bytes just fine, but I'd be interested in the feedback of the asker.

Comment: I think; this may be outdated functionality as I was testing this the write() method does not iterate at all. I'm using version 3.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return code of `spi.write(buffer)` - it should be equal to `len(buffer)`, unless you have overlooked something.

Note that if you're trying to send more than 4 kilobytes at once,  [`spidev`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev) will be unable to handle that data in a single transfer:

> - There's a limit on the number of bytes each I/O request can transfer
>       to the SPI device.  It defaults to one page, but that can be changed
>       using a module parameter.